# Mismatched input in rule of drools

Tags: drools, rules, mismatch

I am trying to run my rule set but it shows :

> ERROR[102]

I added ")" where it is missing and after that The error said that it was in ")" [the added ")" in $transfer1 block]

```
rule "balanceTransfers"
when
    $bus1 : CloudBus();
    $bus2 : CloudBus(id > $bus1.id);
    $transfers1: Number() from accumulate( 
        CloudRoute(bus == $bus1, count(1))
    $transfers2: Number() from accumulate( //<-line 51
        CloudRoute(bus == $bus2, count(1)
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -Math.abs($transfers1 - 
      $transfers2));
end
```

> Exception in thread "Thread-114" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   There are errors in a score DRL: Error Messages: Message [id=1,
>   kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=..., line=51, column=0
>   text=[ERR 102] Line 51:1 mismatched input '$transfers2' in rule
>   "balanceTransfers"] Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase,
>   level=ERROR, path=..., line=0, column=0    text=Parser returned a null
>   Package]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accumulate` syntax is wrong. It should be `accumulate ( Pattern(), fc())`. You are not closing the parenthesis of the pattern:

```
rule "balanceTransfers"
when
    $bus1 : CloudBus();
    $bus2 : CloudBus(id > $bus1.id);
    $transfers1: Number() from accumulate( 
        CloudRoute(bus == $bus1), 
        count(1)
    )
    $transfers2: Number() from accumulate(
        CloudRoute(bus == $bus2), 
        count(1)
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -Math.abs($transfers1 - 
      $transfers2));
end
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

When I helped a college with this error, it was that there was a missing `end` on the previous rule.